# Unity Android Push Notifications with Parse.com

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I have managed to get the iOS push notifications working using the Unity SDK by manually creating an installation using the REST API. I am however having trouble doing the same on Android, has anyone got any tips on getting this working?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Notification Service](http://www.insalgo.com/en/products/notification-service) plugin available on [Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/12808) for local notifications (+ lot more) in Unity. The price is 15$ but it’s totally worth it - according to users reviews.

I am co-author so feel free to ask me questions.